# Nested model/form doesn't create an entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, nested-forms

While delving into ruby's nested models I encountered an issue.

Consider the following scenario,

I have the following models:

- Author
- Book

With the following specifications:

**Author:**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books #I read this is necessary here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300619/models-and-nested-forms

  # and some validations...
end
```

**Book:**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author_id, :name, :year
  belongs_to :author

  #and some more validations...
end
```

**I would like to add a book to an author. Here is my authors_controller:**

```
def new_book
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
end

def create_book
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  if @author.books.create(params[:book]).save
    redirect_to action: :show
  else
    render :new_book
  end
end
```

**And this is the form with which I try doing it:**

```
<h1>Add new book to <%= @author.name %>'s collection</h1>
<%= form_for @author, html: { class: "well" } do |f| %>
    <%= fields_for :books do |b| %>
        <%= b.label :name %>
        <%= b.text_field :name %>
        <br/>
        <%= b.label :year %>
        <%= b.number_field :year %>
    <% end %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= f.button "Reset", type: :reset, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

**Problem:**
When I type in the data and click "submit" it even redirects me to the correct author, but it doesn't save a new record for that author.
After a lot of research I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change authors_controller to:

```
def new_book
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @book = Book.new
end
```

Your form to:

```
<h1>Add new book to <%= @author.name %>'s collection</h1>
<%= form_for ([@author, @book]), html: { class: "well" } do |f| %>
```

And, routes.rb

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books
end
```

Comment: Apparently that changed my routing mechanism... It now gives me `undefined method \`author_books_path'` and refers to the second line of the form...

Comment: Please refer http://blog.dominicsayers.com/2011/08/24/howto-create-a-simple-parent-child-form-in-rails-3-1/ which has child form implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of things.

Controller:

```
...
def new_book
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @author.books.build
end
...
```

View, it is `f.fields_for` and not just `fields_for`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :books do |b| %>
  <%= b.label :name %>
  <%= b.text_field :name %>
  <br/>
  <%= b.label :year %>
  <%= b.number_field :year %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That looks better already, but now it is asking me for a create method in the books controller - any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add `:nested_attributes_for_books` on your Author model accessible methods. The create method on you Author controller doesn't need any code additions to get going.

**Note:** You set the Books controller to render 'books#show' on success. If the app is redirecting you to the author that means the **Author controller** is handling the creation of the book, unless you set it to redirect to author and not the book.